# Visual Studio Code "Renaming Folder"

Tags: visual-studio-code

regarding my post from Microsoft Forum Support I was referred to this page hoping that someone can help me.

Question: Is someone here who can explain how it's possible to rename the folder ".vscode" in ".Visual Studio Code" so that the VSCode Editor works?

For clarification: I don't mean renaming it via Windows Explorer! I mean to rename the Directory (or Folder) from ***.vscode*** To ***.Visual Studio Code*** !

Know what I mean? I think it has something to do inside the Settings of VS Code.

Thanks in advance
Mike (Germany)

Comment: Anything not workin when you rename that folder using the Explorer?

Comment: is `.vscode` not working?

Comment: Renaming that folder, even if that is somehow supported by VSCode, is an absolutely **terrible** idea. I don't even want to know how many thirdparty extensions and other stuff this might break.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a symlink from "`.Visual Studio Code`" to `.vscode`. That would give you a `.Visual Studio Code` folder in your workspace without breaking the way VSCode works.

But you'll still have a `.vscode` folder as well. I don't know if that achieves what you hope to accomplish or not. If you're on Windows you could set `.vscode` as hidden if you like, so you won't see it (unless your system is setup to show hidden files/folders).

Can you explain what you hope to accomplish by using a different name for the `.vscode` folder?